# Use ffmpeg to transcode only wma lossless files and not wma files

Tags: ffmpeg, transcode, wma

I have a list of wma files with wma lossless files as well, and what i want to do is to use ffmpeg to transcode only those which are wma lossless and not the wma files. As we cannot distinguish these just based on the wma extection. How can this be done? It is inherent that the name of the file is not used to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

ffprobe will return details of the input files. If you use grep or similar to look for the codec you're after then put the result into an if..then block you should be able to do this. You'll need to know how to program whatever shell you're using.